# Datepicker For Bootstrap : update bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: angularjs

I want to custom the footer of my bootstrap-datepicker, i want to remove the 3 buttons and do this:

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/CzfwA9tfJ5xbfwAmK42u?p=preview)

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    startingDay: 1,    
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    autoclose: true
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the current footer

```
show-button-bar='false'
```

And add a new div with ng-show if the calendar is opened

```
<div class="footer" ng-show="opened">Horaries:<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button></div>
```

Here is an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8WvmM9AmS8x6iArJzZv8?p=preview

off course, You´ll need some CSS to make it look like you want

Comment: thx for yur example so how can i do if i want the dialer not close when i select date or click a buttons, i want to close it when i click outside

Comment: You have a setting: "close-on-date-selection". You should check the code to know how it works and see if you can do the same for the buttons

Comment: I made some changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/x32oX4DsMQtLDxY3bN1N?p=preview.  Now if you select a date, or click the first button, the datepicker doesn't close